# DbContext.Update Method Sets My Foreign Key To Null

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am currently experiencing a weird problem with EF. Let's say I have the following information in my database. Department ID is a foreign key to the Departments table.

[image]

Whenever I make an update to this record by calling the DbContext.Update method it sets the Department ID to null. The only time that it does not do this is when I make a change to the Department ID itself.

```
var employeeDto = new EmployeeDto
{
    Id = 3 // assume that the primary key of this record is 3.
    Name = "Motea Dave",
    UserId = "123123",
    DepartmentId = 3
};

var employee = Mapper.Map<Employee>(employeeDto);
_employeeRepository.Update(employee, employee.Id);
_unitOfWork.SaveChanges(); // When I set my breakpoint here and inspect _employeeRepository I can already see that the DepartmentId has been set to null.


//Employee Repository
public class EmployeeRepository : RepositoryBase<Employee>
{
    // Repository code here...
}


//Repository Base
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork

    public RepositoryBase(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) 
    {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork; 
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity, int id)
    {
        var item = this.Dataset.Find(id);

        item.Copy(entity);
        item.Id = id;

        this.unitOfWork.Context.Update<T>(item); //unitOfWork.Context is basically DbContext of Entity Framework.
    }
}
```

Removing the Update method and calling SaveChanges() directly does not help either.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an *AutoMapper* problem and not Entity Framework

```
var employee = Mapper.Map<Employee>(employeeDto);
```

If this line sets your `DepartmentId` to null, consult your mapping and make sure you haven't ignored the property, or if need be make a mapping for it

**Update**

> It does not. Before executing _`employeeRepository.Update()` I checked
>   the employee variable first and the DepartmentId (3) is there. It
>   becomes null as soon as I execute the _employeeRepository.Update()
>   method which is confusing.

Then its likely with your repository code, it would be extremely unlikely for entity framework to null out a value with an `Attach` and `saveChanges`

However, you will need to put the relevant repository code in your question

Comment: It does not. Before executing `_employeeRepository.Update()` I checked the `employee` variable first and the DepartmentId (3) is there. It becomes null as soon as I execute the `_employeeRepository.Update()` method which is confusing.